# How to automate mobile version pages in android app using appium driver

Tags: appium

I am testing an android app using appium.
In that few links of app redirect to mobile version pages.
I googled but didn't get proper solution, I wish to know how to locate the elements and perform actions on mobile version pages.
Thanks in Advance....!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're looking to find information about automating tests for a Hybrid app (Native app that includes WebViews with mobile web content).

The Appium API Reference is a great resource to get basic info about hybrid app automation: http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?java#automating-hybrid-apps

The main difference when working with WebViews is that you'll need to change the context of the webdriver to match with the WebView you wish to inspect or automate. Also note that once going back to inspecting and automating the actual native app, the context should be set back to NATIVE_APP.

```
// java
// assuming we have a set of capabilities
driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
for (String contextName : contextNames) {
    System.out.println(contextNames); //prints out something like NATIVE_APP \n WEBVIEW_1
}
driver.context(contextNames.toArray()[1]); // set context to WEBVIEW_1

//do some web testing
String myText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".green_button")).click();

driver.context("NATIVE_APP");

// do more native testing if we want

driver.quit();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer....! If possible please add few lines of code for referrence

Comment: Is there some specific language you're using for this? The link I provided has code snippets for all the common languages for Appium on the right side of the page. Choose the language from top right corner.